# QGIS - how to get the average aspect of a slope

Tags: gis, qgis

I have a geojson of polygons on the side of many mountains which represents snow resorts.  I also have a good digital elevation model.  I want to try to make a calculation field to give me the average 'aspect' of the slope.  Is there any simple way of accomplishing that?  Not sure where to start.